# My CustomTableViewCell's read more/less function crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Thanks for your attention.

I have an app that uses a UITableView as a timeline that shows certain events, The Cell prototype was a little complex because i use multiple labels, a button and some imageViews that automatically change in function of the content of other fields.

In that cell, I have a UILabel, this UILabel can have 140 characters or 4 line jumps, if the text inside the label have more line jumps (\n) or are longer that 140 chars, I take a fragment and only display that fragment and add the text "... READ MORE"; when the user taps on the text, the label change and shows all the text, and at the end, appends the label "READ LESS", If the user taps again the label, it return to the initial state showing the fragment and the label "READ MORE" and so.

When I test this, it works on a device with iOS9, but in devices with iOS 10 (including simulators) It stops to work; it appears that when I Tap the label, the label changes as usual, but immediately returns to their original form. I register only one tap.

Have an idea?, Here is my code that is called to update the cell when the user taps the text label:

```
func cellTextPressed(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let cell: TimeLineViewCell = gesture.view?.superview?.superview as! TimeLineViewCell
    let tappedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = self.timelineTableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
    NSLog ("Text Tapped at:  \(tappedIndexPath)")
    if ((cell.isReasonExpanded) == true)
    {
        cell.isReasonExpanded = false

        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.magentaColor()]
        let attributedReducedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cell.reducedReason)
        attributedReducedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "... "))
        attributedReducedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "READ MORE", attributes: attrs))
        cell.labelReason.attributedText = attributedReducedText

    }
    else
    {
        cell.isReasonExpanded = true

        let attrs = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.magentaColor()]

        let attributedRealText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cell.realReason)
        attributedRealText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "    "))
        attributedRealText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "READ LESS", attributes: attrs))
        cell.labelReason.attributedText = attributedRealText
    }
    let lastScrollOffset = self.timelineTableView.contentOffset
    UIView.performWithoutAnimation
        {
            self.timelineTableView.beginUpdates()
            self.timelineTableView.endUpdates()
            self.timelineTableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
            self.timelineTableView.setContentOffset(lastScrollOffset, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have a method to avoid this.In IOS 9 and older versions, there are no problem with that code; but in iOS 10 there is different.

In documentation, apple says that the delegate method tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is called everytime when a cell is displayed on screen, for that cell. In the older versions of IOS, it appears to be a bug that make this situation don't work, let us modify the view outside of this method whitout callback cellForRowAtIndexPath after refresh the cell.

I Added an array of Bool values that represents the status of the labels (If it have extended or shrinked value of the label) and initialize it on the ItemsDownload Method of my JSON receiver method

I add a condition that evaluates the value in that stateArray in cellForRowAtIndexPath() and put the full or the fragment of the text as corresponds.

finally, in the method posted above, added the change of the value at index path to the status Array instead to change all in that method